# I am currently using 3 for loops, is there any way that I can reduce them or make it more efficient

Tags: java, hashmap, time-complexity

I am using 3 `for` loops which takes much time but loads the result in the correct manner.

Whenever I tried to reduce the loops the code breaks and doesn't work as expected.

Should I use a stream, `forEach` to reduce its complexity?

Below is the code sample which I am working on.

```java
for (Map.Entry mapNewComponent : componentsLaunchFound.entrySet()) {
    for(Map.Entry mapMappingConfiguration : mappingConfiguration.entrySet()) {
        String keyMappingConfiguration = mapMappingConfiguration.getKey().toString();
        String valueMappingConfiguration = mapMappingConfiguration.getValue().toString();
              
        for (Map.Entry mapComponent : old.entrySet()) {
            String keyComponent= mapComponent.getKey().toString();
            String valueComponent=mapComponent.getValue().toString();

            if (valueComponent.equals(keyMappingConfiguration)) {
                if (mapNewComponent.getValue().toString().equals(valueMappingConfiguration)) {
                    finalcom.put(keyComponent, mapNewComponent.getKey().toString());                                
                }
            }
        } 
    }
```

Comment: No; because you are using three independent `Map`s.

Comment: The issues isn't "how many for-loops", it's inherent in the data structure. Why do you need to iterate? Why can't you arrange your data for lookup by key so you don't need to search?

Comment: How expensive are the toStrings?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? Can you provide an example input and the expected output?

Comment: Eritrean    This is oldmap data old.put("Resource+oil","/content/consumer_electronics/product/Sim");
        old.put("Data+Fine","/content/consumer_electronics/product/Sim");
        old.put("Resource+oil","/content/consumer_electronics/product/Sim");
        old.put("Questiswer","/content/consumer_electronics"); ........This is mapping configuration map........mappingConfiguration.put("/content/consumer_electronics/product/Sim","/Updated/consumer_electronics/product/NEWSim");....

Comment: @Eritrean .....This is launch map...........componentsLaunchFound.put("/north_america/websites","/Updated/consumer_electronics/product/NEWSim");
 componentsLaunchFound.put("/north_america","/components/content/CTA");  
Output is mentioned above in question as result.... Sorry for formatting

Comment: @RashmiSolanki Please edit your question and add the additional information to your question instead of as a comment. You can also format the code in the question more easily.

Answer (score 0):

It should be possible to reduce somehow invocation of the innermost loop by moving one of the `if` statements above.

Also, shorter names of the variables may be used to facilitate reading and the map(s) could be converted from raw key-value pairs to those of String type.

Then, map of "old" may be prefiltered to contain only the entries whose values are available as keys of the "config" map.

```java
Map<String, String> mapConf = mappingConfiguration.entrySet()
    .stream()
    .collect(Collectors.toMap(
        e -> e.getKey().toString(),
        e -> e.getValue().toString()
    ));
Set<String> configKeys = mapConf.keySet();
    
Map<String, String> mapOld = old.entrySet()
    .stream()
    .filter(e -> configKeys.contains(e.getValue()))
    .collect(Collectors.toMap(
        e -> e.getKey().toString(),
        e -> e.getValue().toString()
    ));

for (Map.Entry meNew : componentsLaunchFound.entrySet()) {
    String keyNew = meNew.getKey().toString();
    String valNew = meNew.getValue().toString();
    for (Map.Entry<String, String> meConf : mapConf.entrySet()) {
        if (valNew.equals(meConf.getValue())) {
            for (Map.Entry<String, String> meOld : mapOld.entrySet()) {
                finalcomp.put(meOld.getKey(), keyNew);
            } // end-for old
        } // end-if
    } // end-for config
} // end-for new
```

Comment: re *shorter names of the variables may be used to facilitate reading*  Hallelujah!  Somewhere, the misinformation has spread among the rule-followers that longer names are better.  Names should be long enough to understand, and no longer.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly you want to replace the values of your old map (or create a new map) for all keys from the `old` map whose values match the keys from the `mappingConfiguration` map and at the same time are found in the values of the `componentsLaunchFound` map with the corresponding keys from the `componentsLaunchFound` map.

You can try the following snippet, which replaces all three of your nested loops:

```
Map<String, String> finalcom =

old.entrySet()
        .stream()
        .filter(e -> mappingConfiguration.keySet().contains(e.getValue()))
        .filter(e -> componentsLaunchFound.values().contains(mappingConfiguration.get(e.getValue())))
        .collect(Collectors.toMap(Map.Entry::getKey,
                e -> componentsLaunchFound.entrySet()
                        .stream()
                        .filter(clf -> mappingConfiguration.get(e.getValue()).equals(clf.getValue()))
                        .findFirst()
                        .get().getKey()
        ));

System.out.println("Updated Map  " + finalcom + "\n" + finalcom.size());
```